# How add init to es6 modules in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, module, init

I'm using webpack and es6.

I have `page-transition` in webpage [Barba.js](http://barbajs.org/)

I must reinit my codes with Barba Event [Barba newPageReady Event](http://barbajs.org/events.html), I have many separate modules like `menuEvent.js`, `parallaxEvent.js`, `inviewEvent.js`, `touchEvents.js`, `plugins and librarys.js` these modules are imported to `mainFile.js`

[Reinit Code](https://github.com/luruke/barba.js/issues/101)

I dont have any idea how to add `init` to each module and add initialize scripts in Barba Event...

Comment: Please include all code in the question itself. Also have you read the documentation of “barba.js”?

Comment: solution:



`menuEvent.js:` 
export class menuEvent {
   static init() {
        //codes
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------


`Barba.js`
import { menuEvent } from './menuEvent'

Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {
     menuEvent.init()
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> menuEventjs:

```
export class menuEvent {
    static init() {
        //codes
    }
}
```

> Barba:

```
import { menuEvent } from './menuEvent'

Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container)    {
    menuEvent.init()
});
```